# how to do dojo.query() with a specify element as root?

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo

In dojo, how can I limit the scope of searching done by dojo.query() to just the children of an element? This (root) element does not have an ID or name and is not uniquely identifiable in the document. In other word, the root is also a result of another dojo.query(). Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dojo.query('.query', rootedNode);
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/query.html#queries-rooted-at-a-given-element

Comment: Just a heads up. In the manual it's suggesting that we can only use id's to root the query. I'm not sure if that's true but if I pass in a query result as the second option it gets ignored.